# Geocoder returns multiple addresses

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-geocoder

In Android's Geocoder, method `getFromLocation` can return more than one address for a given `lat long`. But `lat long` uniquely represents a location on earth surface, so why does it return multiple objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse geocoding translates latitude, longitude into a human-readable address. However, there are different objects that you may be interested in. For example, you can search the nearest street address, the nearest postal code, the neighborhood, the city, etc. For this reason reverse geocoder returns more than one result.

Please look at this [example in the Geocoder tool](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D40.770272%252C-73.966355).

As you can see the first result has a type street_address, the second result has a type bus_station, the third has a type neighborhood, and so on until the country level.

Hope my answer addresses your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Because a `lat long` position might not have a proper name, or it might refer to different names altogether.

Let's say, it points to the exact center of a square of undeveloped land, surrounded by 4 streets.

Depending on a country's rules & regulations, the owner of the land might be forced to 'attach' that piece of land to one of the 4 streets... or the land might be 'address-less' (only defined by its boundaries). In the latter case, the land might be attached to *all* 4 streets, allowing future purchaser/developer to choose the most 'catchy' address.

Or, a building just got renamed. For awhile, people won't recognize the new name. It's just wiser for reverse geocoding to return both the old name and the new name.

Another possibility is for the reverse geocoding to return "defined" names within X meters around the `lat long` position.